# How to embed a sentence into vector

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I had the sentence.I use word2vec to embed word to vector.For example, consider I have a sentence of 5 words.so I get 5 different vectors(One for each word) for the sentence.Which is the best method to make the complete sentence as a single vector which I will pass to the ANN?

Answer (score 2):

This is an open problem; many approaches exist to creating meaningful sentence vectors.

- BoW models, as Fabrizio_P explained
- Element-wise vector operations (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P08/P08-1028.pdf)

  - Addition (i.e. simply add all the word vector together, possibly normalizing afterwards)
  - Multiplication (i.e. multiply all vectors together, element-wise, resulting in a logically grounded embedding)
- Arbitrary task-specific recurrent functions (http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D12-1110)
- More sophisticated general-purpose approaches (https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02354, https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06726)

Element-wise operations, such as vector addition, suffice for most simple tasks, but obviously exhibit a high amount of information loss as sentences grow larger or the task at hand gets more demanding. Recurrent neural networks are quite good at creating task specific sentence embeddings, but obviously these require training data and some familiarity with machine learning. General purpose sentence embeddings are the most interesting ones from a research perspective, but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: There's been a decent amount of work now with general purpose sentence representations done via Facebook's inferSent and Google's Universal Sentence Encoder

Answer (score 1):

You could use the bag of words concept, as explained here https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/. So that you collect all of you words and put them in a vocabulary. After that you can represent your sentence as a vector, where each element is either 1 or 0, depending on whether the word is in the sentence or not.
For example if your sentence is

> Hello my name is Peter.

Your dictionary will be

> [Hello, my, name, is, Peter]

The vector for your sentence will be

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

If you have another sentence like

> I am happy.

Your dictionary will extend including also those words. So it will be

> [Hello, my, name, is, Peter, I, am, happy]

And your vector sentence will also extend

> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

As an alternative you can also create a vocabulary where each word is represented by a number, so that

> {Hello: 1, my: 2, name: 3, is: Peter: 4, I: 5, am: 6, happy: 7}

And the vector for your sentence will be

> [1,2,3,4]

For each new sentence you will convert the words into numbers using the vocabulary as reference.

Comment: But the length of matrix increases with increase in sentences with unique words and matrix will become spatial.In the word2vec the dimension of the vector is just 300.

Comment: Yes with the first option I mentioned that is the case. But not with the second option. There only the vocabulary will increase with increasing unique words. However the sentence vector’s length will be the exact same as the number of words in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

word2vec is an algorithm to create word embeddings, you can read the details here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec

You can run this algorithm on your own dataset, or use saved word embeddings that Google (or other parties) have been run on billions of documents.

The idea is to map each word as dense vector in some n-dimensional vector space, thus containing much more information about words and their relationships.

Put simply each word is represented by a unique list of numbers, and now mathematical operations are possible on words, sentences and documents.